# Why does vivado HLS split this ap_memory interface?

Tags: vivado, vivado-hls

So I have the following bit of code:

```
int post_quantum_kem_encr(  unsigned char m[32],
                            unsigned char pk[800],
                            unsigned char coin[32],
                            unsigned char c[736]) {
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = m
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = pk
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = coin
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory  port = c
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none port = return

  some_crypto(m, pk, coin, c);


  return crypto_kem_enc_def;
}
```

Synthesizing this and exporting it as IP results in the following IP block:

[image]

My question is, why is `c` split up into `c_d0` and `c_d1`? (Same goes for `pk` and `coin`.) It doesn't happen for `m` so it seems to be some kind of optimization. I however would like it just to do straight single byte access to the memory element I'm hooking it up to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Vivado HLS trying to treat port c as interface to 2-port memory. You can try to add the following directive to force 1-port mode:
#pragma HLS RESOURCE variable=c core=RAM_1P

This solution may look like request to use internal RAM of FPGA, but it seems that it just configures ap_memory interface.

P.S. I found some information about this here (they used core=RAM_2P_BRAM to force 2-port interface): https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_3/ug871-vivado-high-level-synthesis-tutorial.pdf; pages 78-82